# Question about a solution of a partial differential equation by separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I'm trying to understand this text:
http://www.ekayasolutions.com/UCDMath/HeatCondSphere.pdf

But I'm having problem with this part:

> Whe have to solve:
>   \begin{equation}
> \dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial \tau}=\dfrac{1}{\xi}\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial \xi^2} \left(\xi\theta\right);\ 0<\xi<1,\ 0<\tau.
> \end{equation}
>   with the conditions:
>   \begin{align}
> \text{IC:}\hspace{2pc}&\theta(\xi,0)=1,&&\\
> \text{BC1:}\hspace{2pc}&\dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial \xi}+Bi\theta=0,\text{ for } \xi=1,&&\\
> \text{BC2:}\hspace{2pc}&\left|\theta(0,\tau)\right|<\infty,&&
> \end{align}
>   and $Bi$ is a constant.

Then it uses the separation of variables, so $\theta(\xi,\tau)=\Phi(\xi)G(\tau)$ and the problem becomes
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{G}\dfrac{d G}{d \tau}=\dfrac{1}{\xi\Phi}\dfrac{d^2}{d \xi^2}\left(\xi\Phi\right).
\end{equation}

Then, by Newton's cooling law
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{G}\dfrac{d G}{d \tau}=-\lambda^2,\text{ with } \lambda>0,
\end{equation}
so the solution for $G(\tau)$ is
\begin{equation}
G(\tau)=c e^{-\lambda^2\tau}.
\end{equation}
Anb solving for $\Phi(\xi)$ gives
\begin{equation}
\Phi(\xi)=\dfrac{1}{\xi}\sin(\lambda\xi).
\end{equation}

Where $\lambda$ is a root of the equation:
\begin{equation}
1-\lambda\cot(\lambda)-Bi=0.\hspace{2pc}(♦)
\end{equation}

Then it states that the solution is
\begin{equation}
\theta(\xi,\tau)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty G(c_n,\tau)\Phi(\lambda_n,\xi)
\end{equation}

where $\lambda_n$ are all the roots of (♦), and **my question is** why does it sum all the roots and do not just chose one?

Comment: To get the most general result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differential equation is linear in $\theta$, so that means that if you find two independent solutions $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, then any linear combination of those two, $c_1 \theta_1 + c_2 \theta_2$ is again a solution to the differential equation.

In general, you will need *all* the linearly independent solutions in order to be able to satisfy the boundary conditions and initial conditions. For example, you find one solution $\theta_1$, which satisfies BC1 but not BC2. Imagine you're lucky enough to find another solution $\theta_2$ which satisfies BC2 but not BC1. By considering a linear combination of those two, you might be able to choose $c_1$ and $c_2$ just so that the linear combination satisfies *both* BC1 and BC1.

So, the *general* solution is given by
\begin{equation}
 \theta(\xi,\tau) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n e^{-\lambda_n^2 \tau} \frac{1}{\xi} \sin(\lambda_n \xi),
\end{equation}
and value of the $c_n$'s is determined by the initial and boundary conditions. If you're lucky though, a lot of the $c_n$'s will be zero.